# Specific PHP Version can not be installed - not found

Tags: php, docker, apache, ubuntu, dockerfile

I'm trying to install php8.1.5 in a docker container and created this basic Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install php8.1=8.1.5-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.1 -y
```

and get this failure message when I try to build this image:

```
Step 6/6 : RUN apt install php8.1=8.1.5-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.1 -y
 ---> Running in b0a4010be96e

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package php8.1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Version '8.1.5-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.1' for 'php8.1' was not found
```

Regarding this page: [https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+packages?field.name_filter=8.1&field.status_filter=&field.series_filter=](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+packages?field.name_filter=8.1&field.status_filter=&field.series_filter=)

It should be no problem to install this version.

Thx for your help.

Comment: I ran you 4 first commands, then `apt-cache madison php` and got
 `php | 2:8.1+92+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 | https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages`
`php | 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages`

Are you sure about your version number?

Comment: Oh! Then I ran `apt-cache madison php8.1` and got some versions for `8.1.2`, `8.1.8`, `8.1.11`. Clicking your link, I see that the version you mentioned is superseded. I think you should then try to download the `.deb` file and install it using `dpkg`.

Comment: Also, the question would then be, why not use one of the versions available... namely `8.1.11`